# how to show values from 2 tables in yii dropdownlist

Tags: php, yii

I have tables named Equipment and Supply. Now, I am trying to create a dropdownlist to display articles from both these tables.

Here is my form calling a function named getArticle():

```
<?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'article', RefArticleEquipment::getArticle()); ?>
```

Here's the getArticle function:

```
public static function getArticle(){
    $prov1 = RefSupply::model()->findAll();
    $prov2 = RefEquipment::model()->findAll();              
    $records=array_merge($prov1->data , $prov2->data);

    foreach($records as $model){
        $desc = $model->article_code;
        $id = $model->id;
        $options[$id]=$desc;
    }
    return $options;
}
```

Unfortunately this code doesn't work. I hope someone has done this before. Thanks a lot and regards

Comment: Make relations and generat model `RefSupply::model()->with('refequipment')->findAll();`. Then your items will be available as `$model->id` and `$model->refequipment->article_code` for example.

Comment: what if these two tables don't have any relation? because they are simply separate tables without any relations w/ each other and what I'm trying to do is culling data from them to display in a single dropdown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static function getArticle(){
    $prov1 = RefSupply::model()->findAll();
    $data1 = CHtml::listData($prov1, 'id', 'article_code');

    $prov2 = RefEquipment::model()->findAll();             
    $data2 = CHtml::listData($prov2, 'id', 'article_code');

    return array_merge($data1, $data2);
```

}